# When should you use React testing library's "act" function?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I wrote a testing library test for my React component. It fills two input fields and clicks on a button, working as expected.

```
describe("App", () => {
  it("should show the pages listing", async () => {
    render(
      <>
        <App></App>
      </>
    );

    const [firstPageInput, lastPageInput] = await screen.findAllByRole(
      "textbox"
    );

    userEvent.type(firstPageInput, "1");
    userEvent.type(lastPageInput, "10");

    userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/list pages/i));

    expect(await screen.findByText("Odd")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(await screen.findByText("1, 3, 5, 7, 9")).toBeInTheDocument();

    expect(await screen.findByText("Even")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(await screen.findByText("2, 4, 6, 8, 10")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

The past passes, but I get this warning:

```
    console.error
      Warning: An update to App inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

      When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

      act(() => {
        /* fire events that update state */
      });
      /* assert on the output */

      This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
          at App (C:\Users\allan.juan\dev\duda\src\App.tsx:12:39)

      21 |       event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
      22 |     ) {
    > 23 |       setInputs({ ...inputs, [page]: event.target.value });
         |       ^
      24 |     };
      25 |   }
      26 |
```

Ok, then. It seems that I should wrap my interactive code with this `act` function. Didn't see a mention to it in the docs, but let's do as the warning says:

```js
act(() => {
  userEvent.type(firstPageInput, "1");
  userEvent.type(lastPageInput, "10");

  userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/List pages/i));
});
```

The warning is gone, but this time I'm getting a red light from ESLint:

```
Avoid wrapping testing library utils call in `act`
```

It seems that I'm not supposed to do that either, since testing library calls would be wrapped in act by default. So what should I do?

Maybe I'm doing something sketchy in my state handling which is making the testing tool go mad? I'm not well versed in React, so I wonder if I'm doing something that doesn't follow React's expected style.

I'm also open to any suggestions on how I could improve my React implementation to make it simpler or more idiomatic.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { PagesListing } from "./components/PagesListing";
import { listPages } from "./utils/listPages";

type Inputs = {
  firstPage: string;
  lastPage: string;
};

function App() {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<Inputs>({ firstPage: "", lastPage: "" });
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

  function handleSubmit() {
    setSubmitted(true);
  }

  function handlePageChange(page: keyof Inputs) {
    return function handleSpecificPageChange(
      event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
    ) {
      setInputs({ ...inputs, [page]: event.target.value });
    };
  }

  function Result(props: { submitted: boolean; inputs: Inputs }) {
    const { submitted, inputs } = props;

    if (!submitted) {
      return null;
    }

    const [firstList, secondList] = listPages(
      +inputs.firstPage,
      +inputs.lastPage
    );

    return (
      <>
        <PagesListing pages={firstList}></PagesListing>
        <PagesListing pages={secondList}></PagesListing>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>App</h1>

      <div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="firstPage">First page</label>
          <input
            id="firstPage"
            value={inputs.firstPage}
            onChange={handlePageChange("firstPage")}
          ></input>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="lastPage">Last page</label>
          <input
            id="lastPage"
            value={inputs.lastPage}
            onChange={handlePageChange("lastPage")}
          ></input>
        </div>

        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>List pages</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <Result submitted={submitted} inputs={inputs}></Result>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar DOM tree to your issue. Got tired of the pipeline unit tests looking like a christmas tree.

What is happening...

A sub component in the DOM is doing some sort of read/write operation that upon completion, updates state in a higher level component. Since react testing library is fully mounting, the sub components are being rendered and their operations executed.

Since a sub component updates state of the component you are testing, it is actually the render function itself that needs to be wrapped in act() because that is the function that needs to await the state update.

```
it('renders the component and its sub component and awaits it to finish', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      render({ Component, props, apollo, ctx }); // This uses a custom test utility HOC so you cannot copy this as is because params won't be defined in your code, but standard render can go here as usual
    });
    await waitFor(() => {
      const component = screen.getByTestId('my-component');
      expect(component).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

Should you need to get something from the render itself like rerender or and getby func use this pattern:

```
let rerenderComponent;
await act(async () => {
  const { rerender } = render({ Component, props, apollo, ctx, rerender });
  rerenderComponent = rerender;
});
const { getByText } = rerenderComponent();
expect('expected text after state update').tobeInTheDocument();
```